# Problems understanding regex parameters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm performing exercises on regular expressions in Javascript, however I have trouble understanding a couple of expressions.

```
   function validation() {
       val = document.getElementById("text").value;
       if (val == null || val.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(val)) {
           return false;
       }
   }
```

is "/" a valid char? (sure it is) what is it's purpose?, is "/\" a patron?
Also,

```
if (!(/^[89]\d{8}$/.test(val)) && !(/^[6]\d{8}$/.test(val)) {
```

It's similar however I cannot find the meaning of that char in the expression.
Can anyone give me a little explanation on what i'm missing here?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

All regex expressions in javascript are wrapped inside forward slashes, / regex here /.
The hat ^ in this case is to indicate starts with, and the $ is ends with. The hat can also be used as not in some cases. I recommend looking at this site https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285 to understand what is happening. And of course, practice!

Answer (score 0):

In JS `//` are used as regex constructor.

```
`/^\s+$/.test(val)`  <-- In simple words it's checking for empty string.
```

- `^` - Start of string.
- `\s+` - Matches one or more space characters.
- `$` - End of string.